# Why can't I process multiple images at once with this code?

Tags: python, opencv, fft

I'm working right now on a program to apply an FFT to an image to then get a JET image. The thing is, I got a whole file of pictures that are arranged numerically (1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc..) and I'd like to run the program for all the pictures in the file and then save them as individual jpg in the same folders that my original jpg's are in. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


IMG_FOLDER_PREFIX = r'C:\Users\33668\Desktop\Programming\Pycharm\Video to images\main'
IMG_EXTENSION = ".jpg"
NUM_IMAGES = 10

for i in range(NUM_IMAGES):
     image_path = IMG_FOLDER_PREFIX + str(i) + IMG_EXTENSION
     img = cv2.imread(image_path)
     f = np.fft.fft2(img)
     fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
     magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))


     rows, cols = img.shape
     crow,ccol = rows/2 , cols/2
     fshift[int(crow)-30:int(crow)+30, int(ccol)-30:int(ccol)+30] = 0
     f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
     img_back = np.fft.ifft2(f_ishift)
     img_back = np.abs(img_back)


     plt.subplot(132),plt.imshow(img_back)
     plt.title(''), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.savefig(r'C:\Users\33668\Desktop\Programming\Pycharm\Video to images\main\*.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 500)
plt.show()
```

The thing is, I'm no programmer, I'm an art school student, and so I'm just trying to assemble pieces of codes I find here and there, and I know this question may have been asked a lot of time but I just can't do it, I don't know why it would not work ! When I run this program as it is I get an error message with is
'IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.'

I really want this to work, so if you guys have any idea or hint I would be so thankful !